# Set HDMI refresh rate

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

I would like to set my HDMI refresh rate to 100 MhZ as supported by my TV, however using the code below always set it to 60 MhZ:

```
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=40
```

Any idea why or suggestions on how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around on [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=5851), try adding this to your file:

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

That will force a mode even if the Pi thinks it is not supported. You should only use this if you are sure your monitor supports the requested mode.